# What's better to create a function in plpgsql (postgresql) or on a python class?

Tags: python, postgresql, plpgsql

I have this problem, I don't know if I should make the functions on Postgresql DB with plpgsql or if I should make it inside a class on python/java whatever language programming might work.

My boss asked me why I was writing the functions on plpgsql and not on python and I coulnd't give him a reliable answer of why it was better.

I have google it and I couldn't find any information about this. The only thing that I can imagine about doing the function on plpgsql is that if I change of programming language the only thing that I would need to do is to call the function and not rewriting it on the new language.

This is an example of a plpgsql that I write with the help of a stackoverflow member, should I rewrite it in a python class or leave it inside the db as a function and just call the function from a python class?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION createid(idslist varchar[], objecttype varchar)
RETURNS TABLE(original_id varchar, new_id varchar) as
$$
declare 
l_prefix text;
BEGIN
IF LOWER(objectType) = 'global' THEN
    l_prefix := 'GID';
ELSE
    l_prefix := 'ORG';
END IF;
RETURN QUERY
INSERT INTO idstable(original_id, new_id)
select t.x, l_prefix||nextval('mapSquema.globalid')::TEXT
from unnest(idslist) as t(x)
returning *
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Good question. But there's no right answer. Google for "business logic in database vs application". Some people think it's bad practice. But I don't totally agree. It's all about tradeoffs and the architecture.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know how to google it.

Answer (score 2):

There are some advantages of stored procedures generally:

- is possible to minimize moving data to client side,
- is possible to reduce network traffic,
- the server side code is accessible simply from different environments,
- it helps with decomposition on data processing part and data presentation part,
- with secure definer functions you can increase a security to level impossible without stored procedures.

Sometimes these features are interesting and helps to develop very fast and well maintained applications.

Comment: I don't know if what I think about the loop is correct or not, but correct me if I'm wrong. If I make the function in plpgsql it will call one time to the database while if I make the function on python and loop through the array, it will make "len(array)" calls to the db? If so, then the function on plpgsql is better or not?

Comment: It depends what do you do. The loops has same speed, but there are some overheads - data format translations, network overhead related to data processing on client side. It is removed when you use stored procedures. This overhead is pretty significant - more times I increase speed by ten times just to using stored procedures.